Compare two substrings separated by a /
Goal
Compare two substrings separated by a /:

If the substrings are the same, hide the entire string.
If the substrings are different, display only the part after the /.
The string will contain characters like _ and - in addition to numbers and letters.

Original String Structure:
text1/text2
Rules

If text1 == text2:
Output: No text (hide everything).
If text1 != text2:
Output: Only text2.

Examples
Input: ABC-ABC/ABC-ABC
Since text1 == text2, the output is empty.
Input: ABC-ABC/DEF-DEF
Since text1 != text2, the output is DEF-DEF.

I have tried this ((\w+)(?=\/\2)), however, it has the opposite logic of what I need. This wil work in my program:
https://regex101.com/r/jMqT0Z/1
I thought this should work ^([^\/]+)\/(?:\1$\r?\n?)?; the logic is right according to regex101. But it will not work/run in my program.
https://regex101.com/r/cLTHNZ/1
References:
The program that the regex will run on is EPLAN:
https://www.eplan.help/ko-kr/Infoportal/Content/EECPro/2.8/EPLAN_Help.htm#htm/refregex_r_regular_expressions.htm
The sources/rules should be these:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Do you really need a regex? Using eg awk, this is way easier: awk -F / '{ print ($1 == $2) ? "" : $2 }' input

Your example on regex101 seems to have exactly the output you're looking for, so what is your question?

Like this? ^([^\/]+)\/(?!\1$)(.*) See https://regex101.com/r/gOmcfz/1

I gave the link to the wrong regex expression, I see. It was something I tried but did not get to work in my program for some reason. however, The ((\w+)(?=/\2)) did work in my program. The sources/rules should be these: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Skimming through the EPLAN documentation you have a split method for strings. Can't you just split on / and then compare the substrings?

In EPLAN, there is a prefix/syntax that needs to be correct. This is what it looks like in the program: ○│??_??@^([^\/]+)\/(?:\1$\r?\n?)?;│
